# Webpage Section Background is being cutoff on mobil device

Tags: html, css, mobile

I'm trying my hand at building a website from scratch to act as an online CV for networking and job/school applications. I'm very new to html and css, only started about 5 months ago. For the most part, everything has been working out just fine. The only issue is that on mobile devices the background on sections on my page are being cutoff where I would like them to trail to the end of the screen (the right side). On the desktop, it looks just fine. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated. I'm kinda at a loss on what to do.

Here is the HTML and CSS from my page:

```css
:root {
  --border: 1px solid white;
  --noborder: none;
  --light: #262933;
  --dark: #23242c;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--dark);
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.section-segmenter:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: var(--light);
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  padding: 15px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px){
    .section-segmenter:nth-child(even){
        background-color: var(--light);
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        padding: 15px;
        width: 1300px;
    }
}

.section-segmenter:nth-child(odd) {
  padding: 15px;
}

h1,
.section-title {
  font-size: 2.24rem;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .54)
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fd5961;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.icon-params {
  color: #fd5961;
  font-size: 30pt;
  padding: 4px;
}

a.icon-params:hover {
  font-size: 300%;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fd5961;
}

.text-muted {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .54)
}

.middot-divider::after {
  content: '\00B7';
}


/*#region Navigation Table*/

#nav-table {
  border: 0px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin-top: 15px;
  width: 1300px;
}

#navbar a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 26px;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}


/* #endregion Navigation Table*/


/* #region Personal Bio*/

.bio {
  padding-top: 30px;
  /*padding-bottom: 300px;*/
}

#avatar {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#bio-table {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 1200px;
}

#bio-table th {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*float: left;*/
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 350px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

#bio-table td {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 10px;
  padding-top: 0px;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/* #endregion Personal Bio*/


/* #region Skills*/

#skills-table {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 1200px;
}

#skills-table th,
#skills-table td {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*float: left;*/
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 28px;
  width: 5.3%;
  padding: 15px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

.skills-icons {
  color: #fd5961;
  font-size: 5rem;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.skills-label {
  color: #fd5961;
}


/* #endregion Skills*/


/* #region Experience*/

#experience {
  padding: 60px;
}

#experience-table {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 1200px;
}

#experience-table th {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*float: left;*/
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 15px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

#experience-table td {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*float: left;*/
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 15px;
  word-break: break-word;
}


/* #endregion Experience*/


/* #region Featured Publications & Presentations*/

#publications {
  padding: 60px;
}

#publications-table {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 1200px;
}

#publications-table th {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*float: left;*/
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 15px;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#publications-table td {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*float: left;*/
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 15px;
  word-break: break-word;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


/* #endregion Pub &Pres*/


/* #region Projects*/

#projects-table {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 1200px;
}

#projects-table th {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*float: left;*/
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 15px;
  word-break: break-word;
}

#projects-table td {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*float: left;*/
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 28px;
  padding: 15px;
  word-break: break-word;
}


/* #endregion Projects*/


/* #region Contact Info*/

#contact-table {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 1200px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#contact-table th,
#contact-table td {
  border: var(--noborder);
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /*float: left;*/
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 65px;
  width: 17.3%;
  padding: 10px;
  word-break: break-word;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.contact a {
  color: #fd5961;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.contact-icon {
  font-size: 1.7em;
}


/* #endregion Contact Info*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Personal Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="personal-website.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/academicons/1.8.6/css/academicons.min.css" integrity="sha256-uFVgMKfistnJAfoCUQigIl+JfUaP47GrRKjf6CTPVmw=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha256-FMvZuGapsJLjouA6k7Eo2lusoAX9i0ShlWFG6qt7SLc=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.5.7/jquery.fancybox.min.css" integrity="sha256-Vzbj7sDDS/woiFS3uNKo8eIuni59rjyNGtXfstRzStA=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.7/iconify.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="icon" href="images/tab-icon/favicon-32x32.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>



  <!-- #region Navigation Table-->
  <table id="nav-table" align="center">
    <thead>
      <tr id="navbar">
        <th><a href="index.html">Home</a></th>
        <th><a href="#publications">Publications</a></th>
        <th><a href="projects.html">Projects</a></th>
        <th><a href="#contact">Contact</a></th>
        <th><a href="files/name_CV.pdf">CV</a></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
          <img src="images/headerImage.png" alt="header image" width="1300" class="center">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- endregion Navigation Table -->
  <br><br><br><br>


  <!-- #region Personal Bio-->
  <section class="bio section-segmenter" id="bio">

    <table id="bio-table" align="center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="text-align: center;">
            <img id="avatar" src="images/Geolytes/Geolyte1.png" alt="headshot">
            <br>
            <span class="section-title" style="font-size: 1.44rem;">
                            Name<br>
                        </span>

            <span class="text-muted">

                            Job Title<br>
                            Institute

                        </span>

          </th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th>&nbsp;</th>
          <th width="815" colspan="3">
            <span class="section-title">Biography</span>
            <br><br> text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text text text text text text text <a href="link2page" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Link 1</a> at <a href="link2page"
              target="_blank" rel="noopener">Link 2</a>. text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
            text text text text text text text text text text. text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center;">
            <a class="icon-params" href="mailto:mymail@gmail.com">
              <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
            </a>

            <a class="icon-params" href="link2page" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
              <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
            </a>

            <a class="icon-params" href="link2page" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
              <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
            </a>

            <a class="icon-params" href="link2page" target="_blank" rel="noopener">
              <i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i>
            </a>

            <a class="icon-params" href="files/name_CV.pdf">
              <i class="ai ai-cv"></i>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <h2>Interests</h2>
            <ul>
              <li>Stuff</li>
              <li>Stuff</li>
              <li>More Stuff</li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td>
            <h2>Education</h2>
            <ul class="ul-edu fa-ul">
              <li>
                <i class="fa-li fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> PhD Psycology <br>
                <span class="text-muted">
                                Miskatonic University, Arkam
                            </span>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="fa-li fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> MA Psychology<br>
                <span class="text-muted">
                                Miskatonic University, Arkam
                            </span>

              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="fa-li fas fa-graduation-cap"></i> BA Philosophy<br>
                <span class="text-muted">
                                Miskatonic University, Arkam
                            </span>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </td>
          <td></td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
  <!-- endregion Personal Bio-->



  <!-- #region Skills-->
  <section class="section-segmenter" id="skills">
    <table id="skills-table" align="center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="10">
            <span class="section-title">Skills</span>
          </th>

        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>

          <td>
            <i class="fab fa-r-project skills-icons"></i>
            <br><span class="skills-label">Statistical Software R</span>
            <br>Proficient
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="iconify skills-icons" data-icon="file-icons:matlab" data-inline="false"></span>
            <br><span class="skills-label">Matlab</span>
            <br>Proficient
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="iconify skills-icons" data-icon="clarity:command-line" data-inline="false"></span>
            <br><span class="skills-label">Command Line</span>
            <br>Proficient
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="iconify skills-icons" data-icon="file-icons:c" data-inline="false"></span>
            <br><span class="skills-label">C++</span>
            <br>Competent
          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>
            <br><span class="skills-icons" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 3.5rem;">FSL</span>
            <br><span class="skills-label">FMRIB <br>Software Library</span>
            <br>Data processing & analysis
          </td>
          <td>
            <br><span class="skills-icons" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 3.5rem;">AFNI</span>
            <br><span class="skills-label">Analysis of <br>Functional Neuroimages</span>
            <br>Data processing & analysis
          </td>
          <td>
            <br><span class="skills-icons" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 3.5rem;">SPM</span>
            <br><span class="skills-label">Statistical <br>Parametric Mapping</span>
            <br>Data processing & analysis
          </td>
          <td>
            <br>
            <span class="iconify skills-icons" data-icon="medical-icon:i-mri-pet" data-inline="false"></span>
            <br><span class="skills-label">MRI:</span>
            <br>Data collection, <br>proccessing, & analysis
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>

            <i class="fab fa-html5 skills-icons"></i>
            <br><span class="skills-label">HTML</span>
            <br>Novice
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fab fa-css3-alt skills-icons"></i>
            <br><span class="skills-label">CSS</span>
            <br>Novice
          </td>
          <td>
            <span class="iconify skills-icons" data-icon="uim:java-script" data-inline="false"></span>
            <br><span class="skills-label">JavaScript</span>
            <br>Novice
          </td>
          <td>
            <i class="fas fa-eye skills-icons"></i>
            <br><span class="skills-label">Eye-Tracking</span>
            <br>Task design & data collection
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>

  <!-- endregion Skills-->


  <!-- #region Experience-->
  <section class="section-segmenter center" id="experience">
    <table id="experience-table" align="center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:40%; ">
            <span class="section-title">Experience</span>
          </th>
          <th style="background-color: var(--dark);width: 50%;">
            job title, <a href="link2page" target="_blank" rel="noopener">lab tilte</a><br> Advisor: <a href="link2page" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Name</a><br>
            <div class="text-muted">
              <span>institute</span><br>
              <span>date </span>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th style="width:5%;"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <!--Blank Row Seperator-->
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <!-- Removed the underline text decoration on these, because they ARE NOT actually links-->
          <td style="background-color: var(--dark);">
            job title, <a style="text-decoration: none">lab name</a><br> Advisor: <a style="text-decoration: none">Name</a><br>
            <div class="text-muted">
              <span>Institute</span><br>
              <span>date</span>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <!--Blank Row Seperator-->
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style="background-color: var(--dark);">
            Student, <a href="link2page" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Program</a><br>
            <div class="text-muted">
              <span>Institute</span><br>
              <span>date</span>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <!--Blank Row Seperator-->
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style="background-color: var(--dark);">
            student, <a href="link2page" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Program</a><br> Advisors: <a href="link2page" target="_blank" rel="noopener">name</a>            & <a href="link2page" target="_blank" rel="noopener"> name</a><br>
            <div class="text-muted">
              <span>Institute</span><br>
              <span>date</span>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>
  <!-- endregion Experience-->


  <!-- #region Featured Publications & Presentations-->
  <section class="section-segmenter center" id="publications">
    <table id="publications-table" align="center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="width:36%;">
            <span class="section-title">Featured<br> Publications & Presentations</span>
          </th>
          <th style="width:50%; background-color: var(--light);">
            <strong>me</strong>, Name, Name, Name (date).
            <a href="link"><em>Project title</em></a>
            <span class="text-muted">Journal</span>
          </th>

        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <!--Blank Row Seperator-->
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style="background-color: var(--light);">
            Name, Name, <strong>Me</strong>, Name (date).
            <a href="link2page" target="_blank" rel="noopener"><em>project title</em></a>
            <span class="text-muted">Journal</span>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <!--Blank Row Seperator-->
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style="background-color: var(--light);">
            <strong>Me</strong>, Name, Name, & Name (date).
            <a href="link2pdf"><em>Project title</em></a>
            <span class="text-muted">Journal</span>
          </td>

        </tr>

        <tr>
          <!--Blank Row Seperator-->
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td style="background-color: var(--light);">
            Name, Name, Name, <strong>Me</strong>, & Name (date).
            <a href="link2pdf"><em>Project title</em></a>
            <span class="text-muted">Journal</span>
          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </section>

  <!-- endregion -->


  <!-- #region Projects-->
  <!--
<section class="section-segmenter center" id="projects">
    <table id="projects-table" align="center">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="width:43%;">
                    <span class="section-title">Projects</span>
                </th>
                <th style="width:50%;">Ex1</th>
                <th style="width:5%;"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Blank Row Seperator</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Ex2</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Blank Row Seperator</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>Ex3</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</section>-->

  <!-- endregion -->

  <!-- #region Contact Info-->
  <div class="contact section-segmenter" id="contact">
    <table id="contact-table" align="center">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>
            <h1>Contact info</h1>
          </th>
          <th>
            <ul class="fa-ul">
              <li style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-weight: bold;">
                <i class="fa-li fas fa-envelope contact-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <a href="mailto:link2mail">Email</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="fa-li fas fa-map-marker contact-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> Institute Location
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="fa-li fa fa-phone contact-icon" aria-hidden='true'></i> Office: Number
              </li>
              <li>
                <i class="fa-li fas fa-inbox contact-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i> Mail Code
              </li>
            </ul>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
  </div>

  <!-- endregion -->

</body>

</html>
```

Here are some screenshots of the desired outcome on Desktop vs. the outcome on Mobile where the background gets cut off:

[Desktop Screenshot][1]

[Mobile Screenshot][2]

NOTE: I have already tried to add the following code to my css file, and it didn't seem to change anything. I've also tried adding `width: 100%` to the "section-segmenter" class, which also didn't seem to change much either.

```css
html, body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  }
```

Edit update:
Just tried using this code snippet in the head tag and while it did make a change, it just condensed the section further.

```css
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

[![Mobile ScreenShot][3]][3]

Edit update:
I've added a media query that expands the width of the 'section-segmenter' to 1300px when the max width of the screen is 600px. This seems to mostly solve the issue on mobile devices. However, I suspect that this is a rather crude way to solve this, and will only be temporary. I believe I will have to look into changing the units of the widths of my sites tables, likely converting them to % as suggested by user David Taiaroa.

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:600px){
    .section-segmenter:nth-child(even){
        background-color: var(--light);
        position: relative;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 0;
        padding: 15px;
        width: 1300px;
    }
}
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKxt5.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/McBuP.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6HOMr.jpg

Comment: Hello. Make a reproducible example (add html), pls.

Comment: Sure thing. Sorry it took so long, but I've added the full html and CSS to the code snippet. Running the code snippet and viewing the full page on Desktop vs. Mobile results in the same issues I've been having. Looks fine on Desktop, but on Mobile the background gets cut off.

Comment: The view port should help: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

Comment: Hi @TobyHarnish, thank you for your suggestion. I've added the code you provided into the head tag of my html file and while it did seem to have an affect, it only seemed to further condense the section background. I will have to further look into the viewport meta tag to see how it works. Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the root of your problem is that you have hardcoded the widths of some elements.

On mobile screens these elements are wider than the viewport or screen width, so come content extends off the right-hand side of the screen. This leads to the problem you describe as well as other issues.

This is also the reason why the problem got worse when you added the viewport meta tag

Some of the elements I noticed that have hard-coded widths that cause a problem are

```
#nav-table {
...
width: 1300px;
}


#bio-table {
...
width: 1200px;
}

#skills-table {
 .... 
width: 1200px;
}
```

What you want to do is look into using media queries to modify css as the viewport changes,
eg https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp
and or using units that will scale as the viewport changes
eg % or vw instead of pixels.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I suspected something like this was causing the issue. Sorry I'm so late to respond. I have been fiddling with the media query tag and think I've come to a temporary solution, the details of which I will add to the post, but I will have to continue playing with the units fully solve the issue.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for letting me know @sgonzalez